# Top Div positioning and z-index causing problems

Tags: css, html, css-position, z-index

First off, let me say its been about 6 months since I have made a website, so I am very rusty! Normally I could probably figure this out myself...

I have a header div that stretches 100% width and a drop shadow, below that I have a wrapper div with a neg z-index to allow for the top div's shadow.  Everything seemed ok until I tried to add an image gallery in a div that is located inside of the wrapper div,  the images won't pop up.  I know this is because the positioning relative and z-index but I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix this.

I am sure this is something so simple and stupid but any help would be appreciated!

I temporarily threw it on my hosting so you can see the code:
http://graves-properties.com

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a negative z-index on the wrapper  put a higher z-index on the header , e.g., 9999. That will allow the drop-shadow to show and should resolve the image gallery issue.

Comment: Wow, I don't know why I didn't think of that! haha Thanks buddy! I honestly was racking my brain for an hour... maybe its best if I take a break for a bit ;)